# How to use standard , normal non pretty urls routing in framework Nette?

Tags: php, apache, frameworks, url-routing, nette

I want to use standard , not the pretty , nice , clean , neat urls routing in framework Nette  as that way it is dependent on the apache httpd mod_rewrite module, which I don't have available , and pretty url is the default routing in Nette , how to accomplish it so no such url translation using mod_rewrite or nginx is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In Nette it is accomplishable not to use user-friendly pretty  ('hezky' - original translation - ) urls, by using a simple router class ,
either

- a newer way in configuration config.neon like
  `services: - Nette\Application\Routers\SimpleRouter('Homepage:default')`  instead of eg. a config item custom own router factory router: App\RouterFactory::createRouter
- or older one in bootstrap.php way used to be by automatic detection

```
// Setup router using mod_rewrite detection
if (function_exists('apache_get_modules') && in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules(), true)) {
    $router = $container->getByType(Nette\Application\IRouter::class);
    $router[] = new Route('index.php', 'User:default', Route::ONE_WAY);
    $router[] = new Route('<presenter>/<action>[/<id>]', 'User:default');

} else {
    $container->addService('router', new SimpleRouter('User:default'));
}
```

Afterwards urls are accessible by this format `?presenter=nameOfPresenter&action=nameOfAction`, previously without it, it was accessible as `/presenter/action`.

source:
https://doc.nette.org/en/application/routing#toc-simplerouter

analogically similarly as it used to be done in Yii framework by a configuration setting
`'enablePrettyUrl' => true,`
https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/blob/master/book/enable-pretty-urls.md#url-manager-configuration